# How to reuse a query block in PL/SQL to minimize code boilerplate and object spaghetti

Tags: oracle, plsql

Fellow PL/SQL experts, this is perhaps an unanswerable question, but just maybe someone has a brilliant solution.

Today I found myself copy-pasting a very lengthy SQL statement so that I can join in another table conditionally in one circumstance, and not do so in another. Obviously this irks the programmer in me, who now has two copies of the SQL to maintain:

```
IF <condition>
THEN
  FOR rec_data IN (SELECT <complex SQL, pages long>)
  LOOP
    PIPE ROW(....);
  END LOOP;
ELSE
  FOR rec_data IN (SELECT *
                     FROM (SELECT <same complex SQL, pages long> ) x,
                          <another table> y)
  LOOP
    PIPE ROW(....);
  END LOOP;
END IF;
```

How can I avoid having two copies of the same SQL?

Options:

1. Use dynamic SQL and conditionally wrap the main SQL with another query block that does the additional join.  CONS: dynamic SQL is harder to read and work with because of all the escaping single quotes, maintaining a list of bind variables, etc. And, it's string manipulation and that just feels like poor coding. And, I would have to define a record type with all the columns to fetch from it. More work, more redundant coding (I need to do this for dozens of functions, not just one, so it matters).
2. Create another pipelined function that runs the core SQL and returns rows, then in my top function query that in the two different ways. CONS: my code is now split out in an entirely different object, and now I have to not just create types for the rows but they have to be SQL types. A lot of definition just for one function's local use.
3. Create a global temporary table and load it with the core SQL. Select straight from it or select and join conditionally. CONS: now I have a table defined with hard-coded column definitions outside my code object, just for use by that code object. Remember, I have dozens of these functions to write, and I don't want object spaghetti.
4. Create a view for the core SQL. Query conditionally. CONS: separate object to maintain, plus inability to drive variables deep into the view.
5. Use only the longer version (the one with the conditional join) unconditionally, but use fancy CASE/DECODE within it to effectively disable the join (e.g. `DECODE(<condition>,x.join_key,NULL) = y.join_key`). CONS: this is rather hacky, and may not be so easy to get the performance benefit if the additional "table" you are conditionally joining in is an expensive PL/SQL pipeline function. I'm trying to avoid having to call that function if it's output isn't needed.

The desideratum is to avoid having to copy-paste, avoid string manipulation, and avoid having to define column definitions just to fetch something needed only locally. It's like we're needing to do something like this (have SQL read from my PL/SQL cursor var... this is pseudo-code, I know you can't do this as written!)

```
  DECLARE
    CURSOR cur_data IS
    SELECT <complex SQL>;
  BEGIN
    IF <condition>
    THEN
      FOR rec_data IN (SELECT *
                         FROM cur_data)
      LOOP
        PIPE ROW(....);
      END LOOP;
    ELSE
      FOR rec_data IN (SELECT *
                         FROM cur_data,
                              other_table)
      LOOP
        PIPE ROW(....);
      END LOOP;
    END IF;
```

Any crazy-awesome ideas?

Comment: What version are you using? There are different options depending on your version. For example, since 18c, private temporary tables might help with #3 (there would still be many objects, but at least only your session would see them). Since 19c, table SQL Macros might help with #4 (you can manually push variables deep into the SQL). Since 21c, dynamic for loops might help with #1, by simplifying looping through dynamic SQL.

Comment: 19c. I'll look into these newer features later today and see if any of them look promising.

Comment: Thank you for bringing me up-to-date on recent enhancements. SQL Macros look particularly interesting and I think of very useful applications of that construct. It makes working with dynamic SQL much easier. But for my immediate use-case, it still involves creating a database object outside of my function, so contributes to object clutter (though less so than traditional pipeline functions, because no need to create the output types). And I still have to embed pages of SQL in quotes which makes it hard to read, and requires escaping internal quotes, etc.. but the variable injection is awesome!

Comment: And PTTs like GTTs have to be created with DDL, and so have the additional problem that to use them in PL/SQL would put me back into having to use dynamic SQL to break the object dependency since it wouldn't exist at compile time.   But these are really good ideas and exactly the kind of input I was looking for. It's easy over the decades to use older methods and not pay attention to new capabilities that come in the most recent versions. Appreciate the pointers.

Answer (score 2):

Dynamic SQL can be a great technique for handling boilerplate code. In most programming languages, dynamic code is problematic because it's difficult to reason about the programming language and environment, and because string manipulation is ugly. Oracle has a few features to alleviate those problems.

Oracle provides tools like the data dictionary and PL/Scope to make it easier to reason about our database environment and code. SQL objects are easily understandable with simple SQL statements that use views like `ALL_TAB_COLUMNS`.

Oracle has features that can significantly clean up string manipulation code. Instead of endless concatenation and using a sea of quotation marks, we can build cleaner code by combining multiline strings, the alternative quoting mechanism, and a simple templating system.

Multiline strings means simply using native line-endings instead of concatenating `CHR(10)||CHR(13)`. (I'm baffled why some languages in 2023 don't support such a simple concept.) The alternative quoting syntax allows us to specify our own delimiters, like `q'!...!'`, `q'[...]'`, and `q'<...>'` - no more doubling quotation marks. Templating doesn't require a fancy engine, just a simple variable syntax and the `REPLACE` functions.

```
declare
    -- Create a SQL template with well-formatted code.
    -- The variables will be replaced later.
    -- In trivial examples, templating may need more lines of code than concatenation,
    -- but for REAL code, defining the template in one place up front is a life-saver.
    v_sql clob :=
    q'[
        insert into some_table
        select 'a' b, 'c' d, '#VALUE1#'
        from #TABLE1#
        #WHERE1#
    ]'
begin
    -- Set variables.
    -- (In real code, you may need to worry about SQL injection and the performance of
    --  using literals instead of bind variables.)
    v_value1 := 'A';
    v_table1 := 'dual';
    v_where := 'where 1=1'
    ...

    -- Replace the variables here.
    v_sql := replace(replace(replace(v_sql
        , '#VALUE1#', v_value1)
        , '#TABLE1#', v_table1)
        , '#WHERE1#', v_where);

    -- Printing the SQL is useful for debugging.
    dbms_output.put_line(v_sql);

    -- Run the SQL.
    -- (This will get more complicated for bind variables and retrieving results.)
    execute immediate v_sql;
end;
/
```

Comment: Once again, the alternative quoting syntax is yet another new-ish feature that I missed over the years when it came along. That's definitely a gem, and helps make it much more readable. It also makes SQL Macros even more appealing. Thanks much!

Answer (score 1):

The solution that has the least # of drawbacks seems to use normal SQL with a join that is conditionally turned off. In my case, it's an expensive pipelined function whose output I don't always need. So:

```
SELECT *
  FROM (<very long main query>)
       LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT * FROM expensivefunction(in_param => 12345)) s ON 'N' = var_bypass_function
```

Set var_bypass_function to Y or N in PLSQL, then execute the cursor. I've verified with dbms_output tracing that when the join condition is always false (Y=N, 1=2, etc.) it prunes the whole block and bypasses executing the function altogether. So there is no need to have my SQL in two different places.

Answer (score 0):

As there are quite a few conditions and changes of SQL depending on those conditions maybe you could create a small package to get it done. There you could define your long query (just once) and combine it with some embeded variables to handle the changing parts. Here is the basic structure that you should adjust to your environment and needs.

Here is the package:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE 
PACKAGE REF_CURSORS AS 
--
  Procedure Init;
--
  Function Get_Cursor(p_add_select IN VARCHAR2 := 'Select base.* ', p_add_from IN VARCHAR2 := '', p_add_where IN VARCHAR2 := '') RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR;
--
  Procedure Do_It;
--
END REF_CURSORS;
```

... and package body:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE
PACKAGE BODY REF_CURSORS AS
    --    variables to construct different cursors
    m_sql         VarChar2(4000) := '';
    m_select      VarChar2(2000) := '';
    m_from        VarChar2(255) := '';
    m_where       VarChar2(255) := '';
    --
    --    here you can declare all the variables that you need - just once - use them later to fetch into
    c_ID          Number(6) := 0;
    c_NAME        VarChar2(32) := '';
    c_BORN        DATE;
    --
--  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  PROCEDURE Init   AS
      BEGIN
          -- here you can define the part that doesn't change of your pages long SQL and embed some variables for parts that does change
          m_sql := m_select || ' FROM (SELECT 1 "ID", ''John'' "NAME", To_Date(''1987-NOV-27'', ''yyyy-MON-dd'') "BORN" From dual Union All
                                       SELECT 2 "ID", ''Mary'' "NAME", To_Date(''1989-MAY-29'', ''yyyy-MON-dd'') "BORN" From dual Union All
                                       SELECT 3 "ID", ''Mike'' "NAME", To_Date(''1991-JAN-20'', ''yyyy-MON-dd'') "BORN" From dual 
                                      ) base' || ' ' || m_from || ' ' || m_where;
          --
      END Init;
--    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  FUNCTION Get_Cursor (p_add_select IN VARCHAR2 := 'Select base.* ', p_add_from IN VARCHAR2 := '', p_add_where IN VARCHAR2 := '') RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR AS 
      BEGIN
          Declare
              m_cursor      SYS_REFCURSOR;
          Begin
              --  building cursors 
              m_select := p_add_select;
              m_from := p_add_from;
              m_where := p_add_where;
              Init;
              --  return built cursor
              OPEN m_cursor FOR m_sql;   
              RETURN m_cursor;
          End;
      END Get_Cursor;
--    ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  PROCEDURE Do_It  AS
      BEGIN
          Declare
              l_cursor   SYS_REFCURSOR;
          Begin
              For i In 0..3 Loop 
                  If i = 0 Then
                        l_cursor := Get_Cursor();
                  Else
                        l_cursor := Get_Cursor(p_add_where => ' WHERE ID = ' || i);
                  End If;
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(m_sql || Chr(10));       -- test print out
                  LOOP 
                      FETCH l_cursor Into c_ID, c_NAME, c_BORN;
                      EXIT WHEN l_cursor%NOTFOUND;
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(c_ID || ' | ' || c_NAME || ' | ' || c_BORN);   -- test print out
                  END LOOP;
                  CLOSE l_cursor;
              End Loop;
              --
              l_cursor := Get_Cursor( p_add_select => 'Select added.* ', 
                                      p_add_from => 'Left Join (Select 4 "ID", ''Bob'' "NAME", To_Date(''06.07.2000'', ''dd.mm.yyyy'') "BORN" From Dual) added ON(added.ID > base.ID)', 
                                      p_add_where => ' WHERE added.ID = 4');
              FETCH l_cursor Into c_ID, c_NAME, c_BORN;
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('-- ************************************ --');   -- test print out
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(m_sql);                                          -- test print out
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(c_ID || ' | ' || c_NAME || ' | ' || c_BORN);     -- test print out
          End;
      END Do_It;
END REF_CURSORS;
```

The functionality for testing is coded in Do_It Procedure where some loops and conditions are put together and at the end there are some additional data embeded and completely new select statement is set.

The call and resulting printouts:

```sql
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
BEGIN
      REF_CURSORS.Do_It;
END;
/
anonymous block completed
Select base.*  FROM (SELECT 1 "ID", 'John' "NAME", To_Date('1987-NOV-27', 'yyyy-MON-dd') "BORN" From dual Union All
                                       SELECT 2 "ID", 'Mary' "NAME", To_Date('1989-MAY-29', 'yyyy-MON-dd') "BORN" From dual Union All
                                       SELECT 3 "ID", 'Mike' "NAME", To_Date('1991-JAN-20', 'yyyy-MON-dd') "BORN" From dual 
                                      ) base  

1 | John | 27-NOV-87
2 | Mary | 29-MAY-89
3 | Mike | 20-JAN-91
Select base.*  FROM (SELECT 1 "ID", 'John' "NAME", To_Date('1987-NOV-27', 'yyyy-MON-dd') "BORN" From dual Union All
                                       SELECT 2 "ID", 'Mary' "NAME", To_Date('1989-MAY-29', 'yyyy-MON-dd') "BORN" From dual Union All
                                       SELECT 3 "ID", 'Mike' "NAME", To_Date('1991-JAN-20', 'yyyy-MON-dd') "BORN" From dual 
                                      ) base   WHERE ID = 1

1 | John | 27-NOV-87
Select base.*  FROM (SELECT 1 "ID", 'John' "NAME", To_Date('1987-NOV-27', 'yyyy-MON-dd') "BORN" From dual Union All
                                       SELECT 2 "ID", 'Mary' "NAME", To_Date('1989-MAY-29', 'yyyy-MON-dd') "BORN" From dual Union All
                                       SELECT 3 "ID", 'Mike' "NAME", To_Date('1991-JAN-20', 'yyyy-MON-dd') "BORN" From dual 
                                      ) base   WHERE ID = 2

2 | Mary | 29-MAY-89
Select base.*  FROM (SELECT 1 "ID", 'John' "NAME", To_Date('1987-NOV-27', 'yyyy-MON-dd') "BORN" From dual Union All
                                       SELECT 2 "ID", 'Mary' "NAME", To_Date('1989-MAY-29', 'yyyy-MON-dd') "BORN" From dual Union All
                                       SELECT 3 "ID", 'Mike' "NAME", To_Date('1991-JAN-20', 'yyyy-MON-dd') "BORN" From dual 
                                      ) base   WHERE ID = 3

3 | Mike | 20-JAN-91
-- ************************************ --
Select added.*  FROM (SELECT 1 "ID", 'John' "NAME", To_Date('1987-NOV-27', 'yyyy-MON-dd') "BORN" From dual Union All
                                       SELECT 2 "ID", 'Mary' "NAME", To_Date('1989-MAY-29', 'yyyy-MON-dd') "BORN" From dual Union All
                                       SELECT 3 "ID", 'Mike' "NAME", To_Date('1991-JAN-20', 'yyyy-MON-dd') "BORN" From dual 
                                      ) base Left Join (Select 4 "ID", 'Bob' "NAME", To_Date('06.07.2000', 'dd.mm.yyyy') "BORN" From Dual) added ON(added.ID > base.ID)  WHERE added.ID = 4
4 | Bob | 06-JUL-00
```

Comment: The goal is simplicity, ease of maintenance, avoiding unnecessary coding. I know that I can accomplish a reuse of SQL in a half dozen ways, including dynamic SQL, but they all have serious drawbacks when one has to create dozens of these.  John Heller mentioned SQL Macros, available since 19.7, which hold real promise, but still require embedding the SQL in quotes and creating a separate function to hold the macro outside the main function needing it. I'm trying to keep everything in one place, internal to the main function, without copy-paste or excessive complexity.

Comment: @PaulW That is the idea, everithing in 1 package, sorry, but I'm afraid that you will not solve it without coding it in quotes one way or another. That's why the package was proposed. And yes, there are some other options, probably not as closed in one object,though.

Comment: There are several ways of doing it without enclosing the SQL in quotes, as I listed above. But every method has its downsides. I'm looking for the best way, from the perspective of good programming principles.